# how to estimate total IO

Tags: java, sockets, io, netty, nio

I am developing a process that works as a facade for all clients to access data (reports size vary from 100 kb to few MB), with few thousands run each day but exact number is unknown and may vary significantly from day to day.

The motivations behind building façade is we have several servers behind the scene that can generate the data but we want to have some sort of load balancing to make best use of all servers we have also the clients don’t need to know a individual server they need to hit.

So the façade selects a server, round the report and send back the data to client. So there are two IO involved here for a given report

1. Between Client and Façade server
2. Between façade server and the processing node

I know this is little vague topic but how can I estimate the total IO to see if the façade is going to become a bottleneck in itself as all IO goes  through it. Any insight, tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Estimate based on a worst-case scenario.**

You said that the exact number of reports is unknown and may vary significantly.  You really only need to pay attention to the worst-case scenario.  You only need to make sure that the facade isn't a bottleneck on the busiest day.  My plan would be to take the historically known busiest day and double that amount of traffic.  If you make sure that the facade can handle that amount of traffic, then it's likely it will be able to handle anything foreseeable.

Please consider, however, that the returning data doesn't have to go back through the facade.  There are several different ways to architect a system like this where the processing node can send the results directly back to the client when it is completed.  Unless these reports are based on static data and can be cached in the facade, I don't see the benefit of sending the data for all the reports back through the facade when they are completed.

Comment: Thanks Erick, Although i can not use in our current environment given that the report servers are proprietary products and they can only give the report back to the caller through their api but could you share some ideas how can i send the data directly from processing node to the client. may be i will think about having a local client on each node. Also the facade will need to know the task is done so it can take that into consideration when calculating which node is doing how much.

Comment: A custom client on each node to "wrap" the proprietary server would certainly help to solve the problem.  When the processing node is finished, it should create a server socket on which to provide results.  Then it sends the port number and a random authorization code to the facade, which forwards this information to the client for results retrieval.  Although I wonder, if the report servers are proprietary products, what suggestions the vendor would have for solving such a problem.  Surely they have a solution for how to scale their product?

Comment: Thanks  a lot Eric, that is certainly doable. I was doing research around how servelets have implemented request forwarding. The proprietary product does not support any such feature as of now, the whole reason why we need to build something of our own due to the scaling issues.